# MySQL JOIN/UNION

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables containing measurement data (table structure is given by data acquiring software) from two measurement devices. Both have the equal structure: One column "ID", one column "TIME" with timestamps in 2h-steps and one column measurement data named "upltu12_plt". At most times just one of the devices is active, so the other one has no rows for this times. But sometimes both are active and having measurement values in. I try to combine the measurement data from both tables in that way that I have the columns TIME, upltu12_plt_1 and upltu12_plt_2 (containing NULL if there is no measurement value for the device at a time) [wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnhsi.png).
I tried with

```
SELECT TIME,upltu12_plt AS 'upltu12_plt_1',NULL AS 'upltu12_plt_2' FROM sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001
UNION
SELECT TIME,NULL AS 'upltu12_plt_1', upltu12_plt AS 'upltu12_plt_2' FROM sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 
ORDER BY TIME ASC
```

which brought this result [Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lciug.png). The columns are as I hoped for but there are two rows when both devices have data at one timestamp.

I also tried

```
(SELECT A.TIME AS TIME1,A.upltu12_plt,B.TIME AS TIME2,B.upltu12_plt FROM sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001 as A LEFT JOIN sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 AS B ON A.TIME=B.TIME 
UNION 
SELECT A.TIME,A.upltu12_plt,B.TIME,B.upltu12_plt FROM sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001 AS A RIGHT JOIN sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 AS B ON A.TIME=B.TIME)
ORDER BY TIME1 ASC
```

With this SQL statement there are two columns with timestamps ([Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vbdP.png)).
Can anyone tell me if my problem can be solved just using SQL statements and what statement I have to use?
Kind regards Jan-Hendrik

Comment: Please add sample data for your current table, especially include data for the `TIME` column.  Your current union approach is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, you have to use a combination of both `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` alongwith `UNION` to get the desired result.

```
SELECT A.TIME,
       A.upltu12_plt AS upltu12_plt_1,
       B.upltu12_plt AS upltu12_plt_2
FROM   sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001 AS A
       LEFT JOIN sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 AS B
               ON A.TIME = B.TIME
UNION
SELECT B.TIME,
       A.upltu12_plt AS upltu12_plt_1,
       B.upltu12_plt AS upltu12_plt_2
FROM   sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001 AS A
       RIGHT JOIN sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 AS B
               ON A.TIME = B.TIME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible that what you might be looking for isn't using UNION but using CROSS JOIN. [Check this resource out.](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S/O.  What you need is a FULL JOIN (link shows differences between full/cross)

[Full Join vs Cross Join](https://stevestedman.com/2015/03/full-outer-join-vs-cross-join/#:%7E:text=FULL%20OUTER%20JOIN%20and%20CROSS%20JOIN%20do%20not,NULLs%2C%20while%20CROSS%20JOIN%20returns%200%20rows.%20)

A full join, where the connection between is based on the same time will always get from either side, but if they exist in both sides will give what I think you are looking for.

```
SELECT
      A.TIME AS TIME1,
      A.upltu12_plt   A_Reading,
      B.upltu12_plt   B_Reading
   FROM 
      sx1batt101m_c2h1_0001 as A 
         FULL OUTER JOIN sx2batt102m_c2h1_0001 AS B 
            ON A.TIME = B.TIME 
   ORDER BY 
      A.TIME1
```